# Can quotes made with \MakeAutoQuote made robust in a \ulem?

Tags: csquotes, ulem, robust-commands

The following example gives the error `! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup`  because of the `»«` in the `\uwave` command. Can the definition of the quotes be changed to avoid the error *without loosing the csquotes functionality* (I know that simply commenting the `\MakeAutoQuote` works) and without adding something e.g. a `\mbox` in the `\ulem` argument?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\MakeAutoQuote{»}{«}
\usepackage{ulem} 
\begin{document}
»quotes«

\uwave{»quotes«} %error
\end{document}
```

Switching to soulutf8 would be an option, but it gives the same error.

Comment: I think the stuff `csquotes` does will be impossible to put inside `ulem` (but feel free to prove me wrong)

Comment: Afterall the only thing that doesn't throw an error is if you put everything inside a single `\mbox` like `\uwave{\mbox{»quotes«}}`, `\mbox`ing the quotes alone will throw an error, too. You'd have to change the internals of `csquotes` inside the argument of any `ulem` macro, to make it somehow work.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that a solution with ulem is possible. But with lualatex and the new lua-ul package the following works fine:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{lua-ul} %needs lualatex
\font\sixly=lasy6 %from ulem ...
 \newunderlinetype\beginUnderWavy[\number\dimexpr1ex]{\cleaders\hbox{%
 \raisebox{-0.8ex}{\sixly \char58}%
 }}
 \newcommand\underWavy[1]{{\beginUnderWavy#1}}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\MakeAutoQuote{»}{«}
\usepackage{ulem}
\begin{document}
%\uwave{»quotes«}% errors 

\uwave{quotes}
\underWavy{»quotes«} 
\end{document}
```

[image]