Nest textquote of csquotes inside ul of soul and have line-breaks
I would like to nest a call to the macro \textquote inside a call to \ul. The problem is that I need to put the \textquote in a call to \mbox. This is necessary because otherwise the \ul command will not compile.
There are two problems:

I have to wrap all my \textquote calls inside an \mbox
Long lines of text do not break anymore inside the \textquote command.

How can I do the following minimal working example without \mbox?
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{soul} % for colored underlining
\usepackage{xcolor} % for color definitions

\begin{document}

Not underlined. 

\section{Underlined}

\setulcolor{red} % Set the underline color to red
\ul{Underlined in red}

\section{Quoted}

\textquote{Quoted and underlined}

\section{Single line underlined and quoted}
\ul{Underlined. \mbox{\textquote{Quoted and underlined in red.}}}

\end{document}



If you can use lualatex: You could use the lua-ul package instead

\enquote works more or less with soul if you register the command \soulregister{\enquote}{1}, but \textquote has too many optional arguments, this only works with lua-ul. See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/495753/2388 for a similar question.
